# SQL - Should I use a junction table or not?

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I am creating a new SQL Server 2008 database.  I have two two tables that are related.

The first table looks like this:

```
 BRANDS // table name
 BrandID // pk
 BrandName // varchar
```

The second table looks like this:

```
 MODELS // table name
 ModelID // pk
 ModelDescription // varchar
```

Every brand will have at least one model and every model will belong to only one brand.

The question is, should I create a junction table like this

```
 BRANDS_MODELS // table name
 RecordID // pk
 BrandID
 ModelID
```

Or should I modify the MODELS table to include the BrandID like this

```
 MODELS // table name
 BrandID // 
 ModelID // pk
 ModelDescription // varchar
```

Thanks!

Comment: what's with the SiteID on the junction table, how does it relate here?

Comment: Nathan, you'll have to explain your question. The junction table associates the brand with the model. You'd query the junction table with to get the ModelID associated with a specific BrandID.

Comment: sorry, just that i've seen tables like that that were 3-way intersections. wondered if i was missing something important about the relationships where a site was tied to a combination of brand and model.

Comment: Ah, actually --- good catch.  I really do mean BrandID, not SiteID. I am working on something else and have SiteID on my brain. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a model belongs to only one brand then you can put the FK to brand on the model table (your second approach). The first way, with the junction table, is for a many-to-many relation.

Comment: Thanks. I agree. I just wanted to really get some solid confirmation. It looks like we are all in agreement.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you've said so far, I would leave out the junction table and use an ordinary foreign key in the MODELS table.

But if a model could move brands and you needed to maintain a current junction and history, a junction table has advantages over keeping history of the entire MODELS row when just a foreign key changes.  Also if other things exist which might be associated with the relationship "entity" more than the MODEL entity it might make more sense to have a junction table.  You can always make a unique constraint on ModelID in the junction table to ensure that the same model is not linked to multiple brands.  So although a junction table is required to effectively implement a many-to-many relationship, it can also be useful for one-to-many relationships where that relationship itself has attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The junction table is probably more than I need and will create no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Junction tables are used for many-to-many relationships which does not seem to be a good fit here.

For example, you would not want to enable the creation of a Honda Civic and a Toyota Civic. That's an example of car's make/model relationship but should fit your brand/model relationship.

Comment: Ironically, I drive a Toyota Civic. :>  Thanks!

Comment: lol. Really? There is such a thing as a Toyota Civic? How about Chevy/Camaro vs. a Ford/Camaro as an example?

Comment: I'm saving up for a Yugo Pacer :?