# ColdFusion - What's the best URL naming convention to use?

Tags: url, coldfusion, seo

I am using ColdFusion 9.

I am creating a brand new site that uses three templates. The first template is the home page, where users are prompted to select a brand or a specific model. The second template is where the user can view all of the models of the selected brand. The third template shows all of the specific information on a specific model.

A long time ago... I would make the URLs like this:

```
.com/Index.cfm // home page
.com/Brands.cfm?BrandID=123 // specific brand page
.com/Models.cfm?ModelID=123 // specific model page
```

Now, for SEO purposes and for easy reading, I might want my URLs to look like this:

```
.com/? // home page
.com/?Brand=Worthington
.com/?Model=Worthington&Model=TX193A
```

Or, I might want my URLs to look like this:

```
.com/? // home
.com/?Worthington // specific brand
.com/?Worthington/TX193A // specific model
```

My question is, are there really any SEO benefits or easy reading or security benefits to either naming convention?

Is there a best URL naming convention to use?

Is there a real benefit to having a URL like this?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113295/sql-should-i-use-a-junction-table-or-not
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use URLs that make sense for your users.** If you use sensible URLs which *humans* understand, it'll work with search engines too.

i.e. **Don't do SEO, do HO**. Human Optimisation. Optimise your pages for the users of your page and in doing so you'll make Google (and others) happy.

Do NOT stuff keywords into URLs *unless it helps the people your site is for*.

To decide what your URL should look like, you need to understand what the parts of a URL are for.

So, given this URL: `http://domain.com/whatever/you/like/here?q=search_terms#page-frament.`

It breaks down like this:

`http`
what protocol is used to deliver the page

`:`
divides protocol from rest of url

`//domain.com`
indicates what server to load

`/whatever/you/like/here`
Between the domain and the ? should indicate which page to load.

`?`
divides query string from rest of url

`q=search_terms`
Between the ? and the # can be used for a dynamic search query or setting.

`#`
divides page fragment from rest of the url

`page-frament`
Between the # and the end of line indicates which part of the page to focus on.

If your system setup lets you, a system like this is probably the most human friendly:

```
domain.com
domain.com/Worthington
domain.com/Worthington/TX193A
```

However, sometimes a unique ID is needed to ensure there is no ambiguity (with SO, there might be multiple questions with the same title, thus why ID is included, whilst the question is included because it's easier for humans that way).

Since all models must belong to a brand, you don't need both ID numbers though, so you can use something like this:

```
domain.com
domain.com/123/Worthington
domain.com/456/Worthington/TX193A
```

*(where 123 is the brand number, and 456 is the model number)*

You only need extra things (like `/questions/` or `/index.cfm` or `/brand.cfm` or whatever) if you are unable to disambiguate different pages without them.

Remember: this part of the URL identifies the page - it needs to be possible to identify a single page with a single URL - to put it another way, every page should have a unique URL, and every unique URL should be a different page. *(Excluding the query string and page fragment parts.)*

Again, using the SO example - there are more than just questions here, there are users and tags and so on too. so they couldn't just do `stackoverflow.com/7275745/question-title` because it's not clearly distinct from `stackoverflow.com/651924/evik-james` - which they solve by inserting `/questions` and `/users` into each of those to make it obvious what each one is.

Ultimately, the best URL system to use depends on what pages your site has and who the people using your site are - you need to consider these and come up with a suitable solution. Simpler URLs are better, but too much simplicity may cause confusion.

Hopefully this all makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer based on what I know about SEO and what we have implemented:

- The first thing that get searched and considered is your domain name, and thus picking something related to your domain name is very important
- URL with query string has lower priority than the one that doesn't. The reason is that query string is associated with dynamic content that could change over time. The search engine might also deprioritize those with query string fearing that it might be used for SPAM and diluting the result of SEO itself
- As for using the URL such as

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113295/sql-should-i-use-a-junction-table-or-not
```

As the search engine looks at both the domain and the path, having the question in the path will help the Search Engine and elevate the question as a more relevant page when someone typing part of the question in the search engine.

Comment: Agreed. For SEO I think it's the sum of all parts so yes, this is helps. Looks better for humans too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an SEO expert, but the company I work for has a dedicated dept to managing the SEO of our site.  They much prefer the params to be in the URI, rather than in the query string, and I'm sure they prefer this for a reason (not simply to make the web team's job slightly trickier... all though there could be an element of that ;-)

That said, the bulk of what they concern themselves with is the content within and composition of the page.  The domain name and URL are insignificant compared to having good, relevant content in a well defined structure.

Comment: Most of what you said, I agree with. However, it wasn't really an SEO question. It was of SEO, security, and best practices question. I am the developer, so my focus isn't on content. It's on ensuring that the site is secure and takes advantage of best practices, if there are any.  Thanks for you comment though!

Comment: Yep, sure.  But the SEO part of the it was the only bit with any relevance here: there is no difference in security, and the "best practice" side of things comes back to "well... only in that for SEO purposes using SEO-friendly URLs is better").  I don't believe there's a best-practice consideration beyond that.  Obviously this is all very subjective, so this is just IMO.